# Different training and validation results with same input Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to re-train MobileNet for a different multiclassification purpose as:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
     preprocessing_function = preprocess_input

training_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_data_dir,
    target_size=(parameters["img_width"], parameters["img_height"]),
    batch_size = parameters["batch_size"],
    class_mode= "categorical",
    subset = "training",
    color_mode = "rgb",
    seed = 42)

# Define the Model
base_model = MobileNet(weights='imagenet', 
                       include_top=False, input_shape = (128, 128, 3)) #imports the mobilenet model and discards the last 1000 neuron layer.

# Let only the last n layers as trainable
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(800,activation='relu')(x) #we add dense layers so that the model can learn more complex functions and classify for better results.
x = Dense(600,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 2
x = Dropout(0.8)(x)
x = Dense(256,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 3
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
preds = Dense(N_classes, activation='softmax')(x) #final layer with softmax activation
model= Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = preds)

model.compile(optimizer = "Adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And performing training **setting as validation dataset, the training set as**:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
        training_generator,
        steps_per_epoch= training_generator.n // parameters["batch_size"],

        epochs = parameters["epochs"]
        ,
        ##### VALIDATION SET = TRAINING 
        validation_data = training_generator,
        validation_steps = training_generator.n // parameters["batch_size"],

        callbacks=[
                EarlyStopping(monitor = "acc", patience = 8, restore_best_weights=False),
                ReduceLROnPlateau(patience = 3)]
        )
```

However, I do get **significant differences in accuracy, between TRAINING AND VALIDATION ACCURACY**, even if they are the **same** dataset, while training; what could it be due to?

[image: Training Screenshot]

Comment: Dropout behavior is different between training and test, also batchnorm needs training to run long enough to be able to get accurate moving averages for test phase. Please give some details about your dataset stats.

Comment: 5100 images with 69 classes (about 70 images/class)

Comment: Can you report the difference in training and validation accuracy after 50 epochs?

Comment: it stops before reaching 50, but the validation does not overcome 0.4, while test achieves 0.99.

Answer (score 0):

Training a neural network involves random distribution of the data in the training database. Because of this, the results are not reproducible. If you're getting significant differences in accuracy, you may try:

1. get a bigger training database;
2. retrain the network;
3. get a database with more consistent results.

LE: it doesn't matter if you get significant differences in accuracy **while training**. Training is an iterative optimization process, which minimizes the mean square error objective function. It takes a while until this goal is achieved.

Comment: maybe the question is not clear enough, but the point is that I am using as validation data the SAME data I use for training. Hence, reported val_acc should be close to training accuracy, but it is NOT... Why?

Comment: Because the answer provided is influenced also by the other data from the database,

Comment: Perhaps there are few data assigned to the validation part of the training algorithm comparing to the other parts.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the EXACT reason but I duplicated your problem. The problem happens because you are using the SAME generator which runs for training and then again for validation. If your create a SEPERATE generator for validation that takes the same training data as input then once you run enough epochs for the training accuracy to get into the 90% range you will see the validation accuracy stabilize and converge toward the training accuracy
[Train-Valid Acc vs Epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1Po.jpg)